# No graph is being displayed

Tags: html, angularjs, plot, graph

I am running this code and getting nothing in output. There is no error in the buildup but I am not able to find out the mistakes. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue?? Regards

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Dependencies/Angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Dependencies/D3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="Dependencies/nvd3/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script src="Dependencies/Angularjs-nvd3-Directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="Dependencies/nvd3/nv.d3.css">


    <script>
        var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

        function ExampleCtrl($scope){
            $scope.exampleData = [
                {
                    "key": "Series 1",
                    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0]  , [ 1309406400000 , 121.92388706072] , [ 1312084800000 , 116.70036100870] , [ 1314763200000 , 88.367701837033] , [ 1317355200000 , 59.159665765725] , [ 1320033600000 , 79.793568139753] , [ 1322629200000 , 75.903834028417] , [ 1325307600000 , 72.704218209157] , [ 1327986000000 , 84.936990804097] , [ 1330491600000 , 93.388148670744]]
                }];

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app='nvd3TestApp'>


    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <nvd3-line-chart data="exampleData"
                         showXAxis="true"
                         showYAxis="true"
                         tooltips="true"
                         interactive="true">
        </nvd3-line-chart>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved your issue with your code. I didn't load any css so you may have to add yours to make it look right. I would also move your script tags to right before the closing `</body>` tag. That way your code will not run before the dom loads.  This will prevent some headaches in the future.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/OMQqMd

JavaScript/Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']).controller("ExampleCtrl", function($scope) {


  $scope.exampleData = [{
    "key": "Series 1",
    "values": [
      [1025409600000, 0],
      [1309406400000, 121.92388706072],
      [1312084800000, 116.70036100870],
      [1314763200000, 88.367701837033],
      [1317355200000, 59.159665765725],
      [1320033600000, 79.793568139753],
      [1322629200000, 75.903834028417],
      [1325307600000, 72.704218209157],
      [1327986000000, 84.936990804097],
      [1330491600000, 93.388148670744]
    ]
  }];

})();
```

Comment: This is working for line chart but not for scatter chart. I am using <nvd3-scatter-chart> but getting nothing in return. Any idea?

Comment: I will take a  look.

Answer (score 0):

Global functions as controllers haven't been supported in angular for quite a while ... since around `1.2xx`

try

```
 var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

 app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.exampleData = [{
     "key": "Series 1",
     "values": [
      ......
     ]
   }];

 });
```

Comment: Okay, Noted. Thanks :)